# How to style my TextView and Button Image Inside ListView

Tags: android, database, listview, android-studio, styles

I want to make an app that have a list of quotes and author that i get from sqlite prepopulated database

I want to make something Like this
[image]

So in the Left, i have 2 textviews (1 for the quote, and the other one for the author)

and on the Right, theres a image button that everytime i click the heart image goes from grey to red, and if its clicked again, it turn red to grey

I already populated my listview with database, using 2 textviews and 1 image button from another xml. But i don't know how to style the font and change the image whenever its clicked

here is my code

**DatabaseOpenHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mqn.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "quote";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_QUOTES = "quotesText";
public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR= "author";
public static final String COLUMN_FAV = "fav";

private SQLiteDatabase database;

private final Context context;

// database path
private static String DATABASE_PATH;

/** constructor */
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = ctx;
    DATABASE_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()
            + "/databases/";

}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void create() throws IOException {
    boolean check = checkDataBase();

    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

    // Creates empty database default system path
    db_Read = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db_Read.close();
    try {
        if (!check) {
            copyDataBase();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

/** open the database */
public void open() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

/** close the database */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
    super.close();
}

// insert a user into the database
public long insertUser(String quotesText, String author, String fav) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUOTES, quotesText );
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, author);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a user
public boolean updateUser(long rowId, String quotesText, String author,
                          String fav) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_QUOTES, quotesText);
    args.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, author);
    args.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.update(TABLE_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a particular user
public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV },
            COLUMN_ID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular user
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all users
public Cursor getAllUsers() {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                    COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**QuotesActivity.java**

```
public class QuotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView title;
Typeface myFont;
ListView quotesList;
ListView favLV;
DatabaseOpenHelper myDbHelper;
DatabaseAccess databaseAccess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes);

    myDbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

    try {
        // check if database exists in app path, if not copy it from assets
        myDbHelper.create();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        // open the database
        myDbHelper.open();
        myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    populateListView();



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_button);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleQuote);
    myFont =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Montserrat-Bold.otf");
    title.setTypeface(myFont);
    title.setTextSize(20);
    title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 239, 223));

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getAllUsers();
    String[] from = new String[] {myDbHelper.COLUMN_QUOTES, myDbHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.quoteLV, R.id.authorLV};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.quotes_listview, cursor, from, to,0);
    quotesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotesList);
    quotesList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
}
```

**Content_quotes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="hendrasetiawan.mqn.QuotesActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_quotes">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quotesList"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/favList"
            android:layout_weight="6" />


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**quotes_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/quoteLV"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/authorLV"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Everytime i try to set the size of the font / change the typeface in Quotes Activity
i always get an **on a null object reference android** error

**EDIT POST**

My LogCat

(Note = My quoteLV and authorLV are now text1 and text2)
And i try to put text1.setTextSize(50); in populateView()

03-23 17:23:30.621 26550-26550/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-23 17:23:30.659 26550-26550/hendrasetiawan.mqn W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/hendrasetiawan.mqn-1/lib/arm
03-23 17:23:30.953 26550-26590/hendrasetiawan.mqn D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-23 17:23:30.996 26550-26590/hendrasetiawan.mqn I/Adreno-EGL: : QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
03-23 17:23:30.999 26550-26590/hendrasetiawan.mqn I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-23 17:23:32.201 26550-26550/hendrasetiawan.mqn I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database mqn.db
03-23 17:23:32.205 26550-26550/hendrasetiawan.mqn I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database mqn.db
03-23 17:23:32.216 26550-26550/hendrasetiawan.mqn D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-23 17:23:32.217 26550-26550/hendrasetiawan.mqn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: hendrasetiawan.mqn, PID: 26550
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hendrasetiawan.mqn/hendrasetiawan.mqn.QuotesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at hendrasetiawan.mqn.QuotesActivity.populateListView(QuotesActivity.java:83)
                                                                        at hendrasetiawan.mqn.QuotesActivity.onCreate(QuotesActivity.java:78)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-23 17:28:32.266 26550-26550/hendrasetiawan.mqn I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26550 SIG: 9

**NEW EDIT POST**

**content_quotes.xml**

Inside here i only have 1 ListView

**inside_listview.xml**

Inside here i have 2 textViews and 1 ButtonImage

**Quotes Activity**

This java, SetContentView the content_quotes.xml
so when i style everything in content_quotes.xml, i can do it easily

And now, i fetch all of the quotes and author from database
to the 2 textviews (which is the inside_listview.xml)

and everytime i tried to style it the 2 textviews, i always got an error
is it because it came from another XML ??

Comment: Can u post your logcat?

Comment: I already can populate the list view with database, and it works

but when i try to style the textview (quoteLV.setTextSize(50);) then it throws an error.



Ah wait2

Comment: may be that typeface is not in your assets folder

Comment: I think the problem is not with the typeface is not in assets folder, because when i use that font on my title textView, the font changed to what i want

Comment: @HendraSetiawan Are u setting text1.setTextSize(50); this in adapter? Can u post your adapter class as well?

Comment: No no, i put it on the private void Populate View() 

The problem is, i cannot style another XML Textviews on my QuotesActivity but i can style the XML of QuotesActivity

Comment: where you facing the problem in question you said you have working list view. can you please explain the problem.

Comment: Please check my newest Edited Post (sorry because my english is bad , i cannot tell my problems properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style favorite image button:

i haven't seen your code. you said you have populated your list view and have your item with two text views and an image button. 
Change from image button to check box so turning heart button into red and gray will be easy.

in your item.xml have check box like this.

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:button="@null"
    android:id="@+id/id_homeListing_fav"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/fav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

note drawableTop tag its pointing to the fav.xml file, in your fav.xml file specify drawables for different states like checked and unchecked

note button tag which is null

code for fav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fav_primary" android:state_checked="true"></item>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fav_gray" android:state_checked="false"
    />
```

in above fav.xml 
ic_fav_primary is your red icon and the other is gray icon.

then setOnChangeListner to the check box and do the actions accordingly.

and for customizing the text font [See this Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the CheckBox codes ! and as for the fonts, i already know how to use Typeface for custom fonts, but the problem is, because the 2 textViews (quotes and author) and the ListView is a different XML, i cannot style the two textViews, because its not connected with ListView Activity

Comment: you passing the context to the adapter?

Comment: Sorry , i dont know whats context, i'm a beginner at this.

can i send you the data and check it ? so it will be more clearer.

sorry for hassle im causing

Comment: Thank you !!, wait i'm still uploading the file to gmail. :)

Comment: Its sent! the subject is StackOverFlow my project. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**To change the font:**

1. Download the font you would like to use from the internet. This seems to be almost the same as your image: http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/typoforge-studio/cervo?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=cervo
2. Create a `src/main/assets/fonts/` folder
3. Move the downloaded `ttf` or `otf` font file to the folder
4. Apply the downloaded font:
   `Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf");
   txtyour.setTypeface(type);`

**To change the image after clicking on the layout**

```
yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          yourImageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image);
     }
});
```

**Add some padding to both the TextView and the ImageView**

```
android:padding="8dp"
```

This should give you an idea of how to style your layouts

Comment: I already use that and it works, but , quoteLV and authorLV is on another XML, and i don't know why, its always throws an error

Comment: You might want to check this guide: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_layout

Comment: That could help you style everything in XML and use an adapter. It's much easier to implement and style your layouts. This would also fix the null pointer exception